# Filtering out distinct donation records from a customer already in result set

Tags: ssms-2012, donations

I need to find the top 50 largest donations from distinct customers. I can get the top 50 donation records, but several of those donation records are from the same customer. Is there a way to filter out donation records from a customer who already appears in the result set? Below is what I have to identify the top 50 donations:

```
SELECT TOP 50 gift_key
 , customerName
 , giftAmount
 , giftDate
FROM gift (nolock)
JOIN customer (nolock) on gift_customer_key = customer_key
ORDER BY giftAmount desc
```